# Compare all the DIVs in LI and set the max height to the DIV to other DIVs in LI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've some code some thing like below:

HTML:

```
    <ul id="product-matrix" class="clearfix">
    <li class="product product-medium">
        <a href="#" class="showQuickViewPan">
            <img src="../images/556116.jpg" class="product-image" height="243" width="243" />
        </a>    
        <div class="swatch-container">
          <p class="visually-hidden">Color Options:</p>
        </div>   
        <div class="product-info">
          <h2> <a href="#"> Travelpro FlightPro Rolling Tote</a> </h2>
          <p class="price-original price-small"> <span>regular&nbsp;</span>$299.99</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ratings-info">
            <a class="ratingsimage" href="#"><img src="../images/rating-5.0.gif" alt=""/></a>
            <span class="reviewcount">(<a href="#">5</a>)</span>
        </div>    
        <img src="../images/Online_Exclusive_v1_m56577569836982197.gif" alt="" />    
        <img src="../images/OnlyAtKohls_Burg_v1_m56577569836982195.gif" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="product product-medium">
        <a href="#" class="sr-item-new"><span class="sr-new-img"></span>
            <img src="../images/742063_Black.jpg" class="product-image" height="243" width="243"/>
        </a>
        <div class="swatch-container">
            <p class="visually-hidden">Color Options:</p>
            <ul class="clearfix"><li></li></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="product-info">
            <h2><a href="#">Columbia Wool Jacket</a></h2>
            <p class="price-original"><span>original&nbsp;</span>$200.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ratings-info">
            <a class="ratingsimage" href="#"><img src="../images/rating-5.0.gif" alt=""/></a>
            <span class="reviewcount">(<a href="#">5</a>)</span>
        </div>
        <img src="../images/Online_Exclusive_v1_m56577569836982197.gif" />
        <img src="../images/Online_Exclusive_v1_m56577569836982197.gif" />
     </li>
...
    </ul>
```

In the above code the **product-info** DIV may have 2 to 10 lines of text so now What I'm trying to achieve is I want to calculate the height() of **product-info** DIV and assign the same height to all the product-info DIVs in all the LIs, which I'm unable to solve. any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Find max height and then set to all other divs with jQuery.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(".product-info").each(function(){
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());     
    });
    $(".product-info").height(maxHeight);
});​
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer! The usual (documented) syntax with [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/) (and JS in general) is `$(document).ready()`, no quotes...it may work either way, but you shouldn't rely on that

Comment: @nbrooks it actually won't work at all with `'document'` AFAIK.

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah I just tried it out, you're right it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of `$.map` to get all the heights at once, and then use `Math.max.apply` to find the maximum value of that set:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, $(".product-info").map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
}));
$(".product-info").height(max);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/q8gzz/1/

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery, you can retrieve the height of your DIV after page loading and apply this value to the others elements :

```
$('document').ready({
    var newHeight = $('#product-info').height();
    $('li').each(function(){
        $(this).height(newHeight);
    });
});
```

Comment below is correct, there is no element ID to take as reference. So add an ID to the reference element and replace "#product-id"

Comment: might need to use css attribute and not height, e.g $(this).css('height', newHeight+'px');

Comment: Your current code doesn't work, there is no element with id of `product-info` in the markup and height returns the height of first selected element.

Comment: Why? If only a number is provided for the value, jQuery assumes a pixel unit, then have the save behaviour than the .css() function. Isn't it?